# html inserted with jquery returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use jquery to add html codes within divs after loading the page for a good final result

For example, after loading the page using the jquery to add this html in the div named "rows"

```
<div class="rows"></div>
```

After loading

```
<div class="rows">
   <div class="comment1"></div>
   <div class="comment2"></div>
   <div class="comment3"></div>
</div>
```

and I also use this code in order to calculate the amount of divs inside the div "rows"

```
    var cont = $('div.rows  div').length();
```

However it returns 0 , but if the divs are added in the own code of the page it usually calculates, what can be ?

Answer (score 2):

1. [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) is a property, **not** a jQuery method. Thus you do not use the `()` with it.
2. You must reset the variable **after** content is added.

For example:

```
var cont = $('div.rows  div').length;
function addRows(){
    // Code to add rows, followed by a callback to set the value of the variable cont
    cont = $('div.rows  div').length;
}
```

Note: because we have `var cont` outside the function, the updated value is global.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there is no `length()` method on that object. It is a property. All you have to do is get the property from the object.

```
var cont = $('div.rows  div').length;
```

Each time you add, append, or delete to the DOM element `.rows`, you will need to re-calculate, unfortunately.

Furthermore, `cont` is not a very good name for a variable. I could understand if it held an array or object, but it doesn't. It holds an integer. `divCount` would be a better name.

[JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/__defineGetter__/0j6ufok6/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want match all the closest children use '>' it return an array and it already has a property length.

```
 var cont = $('div.rows>div').length;
    alert(cont);
```